# Analytic maps from $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb D-\{1/2,1/3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F$ be the family of analytic maps from the unit disk $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb D-\{1/2,1/3\}$, then can we find a constant $M<1$ such that for any $f\in F$, $|f'(0)|\leq M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a constant exists, by a normal family argument. Let $M = \sup\{|f'(0)|: f\in F\}$ and pick a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $F$ such that $|f_n'(0)|\to M$. Pass to a locally uniformly convergent subsequence, still called $f_n$. As a consequence of [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), the limit $f=\lim f_n$ is either constant or is also a member of $F$. Locally uniform convergence of analytic functions passes to their derivatives; thus,  $|f'(0)|=\lim |f_n'(0)| = M$. It follows that $f$ is nonconstant and therefore belongs to $F$. Since $f$ does not fall into the equality case of the Schwarz lemma, $|f'(0)|<1$.

Note that we don't actually need two omitted values; one is enough.

---

If you want a concrete estimate for $M$, consider a covering map $\phi:\mathbb D\to\mathbb D\setminus \{0\}$, such as 
$$\phi(z) = \exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$$
For $f\in F$, the composition 
$$\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{f(z)-1/3}{1-f(z)/3}\right)$$
is analytic in $\mathbb D$ and therefore admits a single-valued branch. Apply the Schwarz-Pick lemma to this branch, and calculate with the chain rule. A nontrivial estimate for $|f'(0)|$ should follow.

Comment: @user147263But how can we make sure there exist such subsequence?

Comment: @user98619 By definition of supremum, for every $n$ there exists $f_n\in F$ such that $|f_n'(0)|>M-1/n$.

Comment: I mean do you need to prove F is normal.Then there exist locally uniform convergent subsequence.And do we need show M is larger than 0?

Comment: @user98619 All functions in $F$ are bounded by $1$, so the simple version of Montel's theorem gives normality. That $M>0$ is a consequence of the argument. Alternatively, note  that  the map $f'(z) = z/4$ is in $F$.